# No menu bars after upgrading to 14.04LTS

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

Up graded from 13.10 to 14.04 using pop up upgrade recommendation. No problems during upgrade. After restarting and logging in, none of the enu bars are visible. Displays desktop image and mouse can be seen, but unable to open anything or even shut it down properly. Any idea what might have happened and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in{enter your passward}.
2. Enter this command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
3. Then run it by doing this:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   ccsm
   ```

   The first part tells the terminal which display you want it to load on (otherwise it won't have a clue).
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes) to get back to the graphical display where there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager screen sitting there.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter this command `ccsm`
6. now find unity plugin and enable it.

Comment: This may have been helpful right up until I tried to reinstall 13.04 from USB and when that didn't work... using gparted to try (unsuccessfully) to format the drive. Now all I get is aa black screen. The encryption seems to be preventing me from formating. Maybe that interfered with the upgrade...?